# What is the name of this solitaire game?

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

I am looking for the name of a card game I played as a kid, but do not remember it's name.

I found it in a Donald Duck book about the scouts (that I remember)

It was played as a solitaire game with 1 deck.

You put out 6(or 8?) cards open on the table, hold the others closed in
your hand.

You keep adding cards till you can do the check and till you left with no cards in you hands. With a bad shuffle you end op with a lot of cards on the table.

1. you check if card 1 and card 3 are the same suit or the same number.
2. In this the case, put card 2 on top op card 1 and go back to step 1
3. Are the not the same, check card 2 and 4 and check if they have the
   same suit or number.
4. In this case, put card 3 on top of car 2 and go back to step 2.
5. If you have no cards on table to match add 1 card from you hand.

The games finished when all cards are distributed on the table.
You win if there are only two piles left. On the left all cards, on the
right one card.
Can anyone tell me the name of the game?

Comment: The rules seem incomplete. Assume you go through steps 1, 2, back to 1, and card 3 is again the same suit or number as card 2 (now on top of stack 1): there is no card 2 to move to stack 1, so what do you do? Same problem with the 3-4 loop.

Plus the rules don't do anything about cards 5+. And where does rule 5 add the card(s)?

Comment: You keep adding cards till you can do the check and till you left with no cards in you hands.
With a bad shuffle you end op with a lot of cards on the table.

Comment: Repeating the introduction does not address the issue: the rules are incomplete.  How does one "add cards"? That is, to which piles and in which order?  And, despite this, note that there are still no rules that can diminish the sizes of stacks 4+.  Since you start with 6 piles, you will always have at least three non-empty piles (4, 5, and 6), thus the game is unwinnable.

Comment: It sounds similar (thought not exactly the same) as the game being asked about in this other question. http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/what-is-the-name-of-this-solitaire-card-game

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant of the game Accordian. Here are the [rules for Accordian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_(solitaire))