# Can you identify this form of solitaire

Tags: identify-this-game

I learned this as a kid. The setup is one card laid out at a time in a row. You make stack cards next to each other if they match numbers or suits. You may also stack in the same manner but skipping two cards backward toward the first card played. The object is to get all 52 cards into a single stack.

I’ve never heard the name of this solitaire but always referred to it as Satans Solitaire because its easy to play but the devils own time to beat.

Anyone else know this game, have a name for it, or variants?

Comment: If that is not the same; this other one might be: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32706/what-is-the-name-of-this-solitaire-game?rq=1

Comment: Looks like it might be accordion!  If you want to drop that as an answer I’d be happy to give you the upvote and check